# Can an InDesign file be seamlessly exported as a working website?

Tags: adobe-indesign

My boss is convinced that an InDesign mockup can be moved to the web with a click of a button. Can someone please confirm or deny this? As far as I know, InDesign is for text publications and can only be used to create a DESIGN and not an actual website itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only export images and text, no links, drawings, lines, etc.

http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/export-content-html-cs5-5.html

Comment: It is also possible to export InDesign files to HTML-Websites via Export/HTML-Dialog. The output is a HTML file with CSS/JS and assets like images.

The result however can be really bad since not all layout information is transferred correctly to HTML. For simple layouts it could work though.

Answer (score 1):

maybe not exactly what you want but try DPS to make a web app from InDesign:

http://tv.adobe.com/watch/creative-cloud-for-design/introduction-to-adobe-indesign-cc-and-digital-publishing-suite-single-edition/